# Unparseable date: "Tue Jun 20 14:45:55 MYT 2017"

Tags: java, android, simpledateformat, date-format

i have searched through many posts and find a solution to parse this date

**"Tue Jun 20 14:45:55 MYT 2017"**

I have tried below formats:

**EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy**

**E MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy**

but it still give me the unparseable date exception.
Anyone can help with this?
Besides, this is the code i used to parse the date:

```
 SimpleDateFormat formatInput = new SimpleDateFormat(inputDateFormat); 

 Date date = formatInput.parse(dateStr);
```

Comment: Did you search before asking? I’m convinced you could have found the answer faster that way. It’s in *many* questions on Stack Overflow already.

Comment: In case anyone is reading this question who either uses Java 8 or later or is ready to adopt a library for your Android app: Stay off the long outdated `SimpleDateFormat` class. For one thing it generally leaves you in a dark about what’s wrong when you make some error like for instance this one. For Android, get [ThreeTemABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP). For all, use `DateTimeFormatter`, it’s some bit more helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short texts for month and epoche are locale dependend, adding the US locale should help:

```
new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy", Locale.US);
```

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Comment: @BasilBourque I know this. But i also know that most companies uses Java Versions lower than 8 (especially in year 2017) which was the date of the answer

Comment: My comment is information for those people reading in 2018 and later, *not* a criticism of your Answer. Your Answer is technically correct but now outmoded.

Comment: As for Java 6 and Java 7, most of the *java.time* functionality was back-ported in the [*ThreeTen-Backport*](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project. Further adapted for older Android in the *ThreeTenABP* project.

Answer (score 1):

> Tue Jun

is a locale dependent component of the Date you want to obtain

do instead use a **SimpleDateFormat** contructor giving the locale

```
new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy", Locale.US);
```

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Comment: I know this. But i also know that most companies uses Java Versions lower than 8 (especially in year 2017) which was the date of the answer –

Comment: Not a criticism. I’m speaking to the readers of today.